# Construct a new probability measure without changing its marginals

Tags: probability-theory, marginal-probability

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant to record. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

Anyway, it is written as problem. Have fun! :)

---

Let $X, Y$ be second-countable topological spaces. Then the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X \times Y$ coincides with the product of those of $X,Y$. Let $\mu, \nu$ be Borel probability measures (b.p.m.) on $X,Y$ respectively. Let $\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)$, i.e., $\pi$ is a b.p.m on $X\times Y$ with marginals $\mu$ on $X$ and $\nu$ on $Y$. Let $X',Y'$ be Borel subsets of $X,Y$ respectively such that $\pi( X' \times Y')>0$. We define a b.p.m. $\pi'$ on $X'\times Y'$ by
$$
\pi'(B) := \frac{\pi(B)}{\pi(X' \times Y')}
$$
for all Borel subset $B$ of $X' \times Y'$. Let $\mu' := P_\sharp^{X'} \pi'$ and $\nu' := P_\sharp^{Y'} \pi'$ be the marginals of $\pi'$ on $X'$ and $Y'$ respectively. Here $P^{X'}, P^{Y'}$ are the projection maps. Let $\pi^* \in \Pi(\mu', \nu')$. We define a b.p.m. on $X \times Y$ by
$$
\overline \pi (B) := \pi(X' \times Y') \pi^*(B \cap (X'\times Y')) + \pi(B \cap (X'\times Y')^c)
$$
for all Borel subset $B$ of $X \times Y$.

> Then $\overline \pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all Borel subset $B$ of $X$, we have
\begin{align}
\overline \pi (B \times Y) &= \pi (X' \times Y') \pi^* ((B \times Y) \cap (X' \times Y')) + \pi ((B \times Y) \cap (X' \times Y')^c) \\
&= \pi (X' \times Y') \pi^* ((B \cap X') \times Y') + \pi ((B \times Y) \cap (X' \times Y')^c) \quad (\star) \\
&= \pi (X' \times Y') \mu' (B \cap X') + \pi ((B \times Y) \cap (X' \times Y')^c) \\
&= \pi (X' \times Y') \pi' ((B \cap X') \times Y') + \pi ((B \times Y) \cap (X' \times Y')^c) \\
&= \pi (X' \times Y') \frac{\pi ((B \cap X') \times Y')}{\pi (X' \times Y')} + \pi ((B \times Y) \cap (X' \times Y')^c) \\
&= \pi ((B \cap X') \times Y') + \pi ((B \times Y) \cap (X' \times Y')^c) \\
&= \pi ((B \times Y) \cap (X' \times Y')) + \pi ((B \times Y) \cap (X' \times Y')^c) \quad (\star\star) \\
&= \pi (B \times Y) \\
&=\mu(B).
\end{align}

In $(\star)$ and $(\star\star)$, we use $(B \times Y) \cap (X' \times Y') = (B \cap X') \times Y'$.